# Images getting darker in typo3 frontend

Tags: image, typo3-8.x

I am using Typo3 8.7.11. The problem is, when I see an uploaded image in frontend, it is getting darker. I am uploading the correct image from backend. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 is using ImageMagick (or GraphicsMagick) to resize images, or do other stuff like cropping. While this is done the palette may change resulting in darker images.
This happens with images which use the sRGB color palette. You can get a clean handling without color changes if you configure

```
[GFX][colorspace] = sRGB
```

in the install-tool.

Comment: I've managed this by selecting ImageMagick and then by clearing the temp folder and the table sys_file_processedfile.  And by setting [GFX][colorspace] = sRGB .. Thanks for the reply.